# Compound indexes in MongoDB - is my understanding correct?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

this is an example question to see whether my understanding of indexing is correct.

Example query:

```
User.find({
    active: true, // not a banned/inactive user
    access_level: ‘user’, // not an admin
    username: /^John/ // starts with ‘John’, or whatever search term
})
```

Would the following compound index be the most efficient for running this query regularly?

```
User.createIndex({ active: -1, access_level: -1, username: 1 })
```

My understand is that, this would sort firstly by `active` descending so `true` would be first in the list, then by `access_level` descending so `user` would come before `admin` and finally sort by `username` ascending.

If my understanding is correct, this should be the most efficient index for this query. Could anyone let me know if I have completely missed the idea here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of indexing is correct. The compound index { active: -1, access_level: -1, username: 1 } should be the most efficient for running the given query regularly.

By using this index, the database can efficiently perform the query by first finding all documents with ***active: true***, then filtering further by ***access_level: user***, and finally finding the subset of documents that match the regular expression on ***username***.